# Exclude indices from Pytorch tensor

Tags: pytorch

I have an MxN table of distances between two distinct sets of points of size M <= N. I would like to find associate to each point of the first set M points in the second set in the following way.

Suppose that the shortest of all pairwise distances is between the *i<sub>0</sub>* point of the first set and the *j<sub>0</sub>* of the second. Then we attribute point *i<sub>0</sub>* of the first set to *j<sub>0</sub>* in the second. For the second pair, I have to find *i<sub>1</sub> != i<sub>0</sub>* and *j<sub>1</sub> != j<sub>0</sub>* such that the distance is minimal among remaining non-paired points.

I figure that I could do the first step by using `torch.min` function that will deliver me both minimal value as well as its 2d index in the matrix. But for the next steps I'll need to each time exclude a row a colunm, while keeping their original indices.

In other words, if I have a 3x4 matrix, and my first element is (1,2), I would like to be left with a 2x3 matrix with indices `0,2` and `0,1,3`. So that, if my second desired element position in the original matrix is, say (2,3) I will be given (2,3) as a result of performing `torch.max` on the matrix with excluded row and column, rather than (1,2) again.

P.S. I could reach my goal by replacing the values in row and column I'd like to exclude by, say, positive infinities, but I think the question is still worth asking.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the "replace by infinity" solution?

Comment: Well, nothing real, apart of aesthetics, tbh.

Comment: I did replace rows and columns with large positive numbers, because I have very few points in both sets and the matrix is disposable. But assuming the number of points is large, excluding rows and columns for a similar task may theoretically improve performance by a factor of up to 3.